# Node.js 18 JS File Can't Import JS File In Repo

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, node-modules

I am using these commands in `/server/package.json` to build and run my server code:

```
"start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\""
```

These scripts build my JavaSCript from my TypeScript source just fine. But when node/nodemon runs `/server/dist/index.js` it errors with this error:

`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/.../server/dist/graphql/typeDefs' imported from /Users/.../server/dist/index.js`

I know the paths are correct: If I Cmd + click on the relative path ie `./graphql/typeDefs` on line 9 of `server/dist/typeDefs` (where the error occurs) in VSCode it opens that file up in a new tab. The corresponding TS file that the JS is generated from: https://github.com/currenthandle/next-apollo/blob/jwt/server/src/index.ts#L10

If I switch the `import`s to `require`s then it works...

Can anyone see what is going wrong there? I'm using node.js version v18.12.1

[image: Generated file tree in /server/dist]

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "eth-saturday",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.2.2",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.7.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "next-auth": "^4.18.6",
    "zod": "^3.19.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.13",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "prisma": "^4.7.1",
    "rollup": "^3.7.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

Comment: If I manually change the import in the generated js to include the .js file extension for the relative imports than it works file. This isn't practical unless I can use tsc or something to do this for me programmatically.

Comment: I found a hacky solution. In the TS files if I do my relative imports like this: `import typeDefs from './graphql/typeDefs.js';` then the compiled JS files work fine.

Comment: Changing the `"module": "commonjs"` solves the import issue but results in top-level `async` breaking.